# Restore NuGet Package in TeamCity Build and Deploy Step

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, nuget-package

My Build and Deploy step in TeamCity is not successfully executed.
It is showing

> "This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props."

Below is the step process log:

```
[Step 1/1] WebApplication2.sln.teamcity: Build target: TeamCity_Generated_Build
[22:31:54][WebApplication2.sln.teamcity] TeamCity_Generated_Build
[22:31:54][TeamCity_Generated_Build] MSBuild
[22:31:54][MSBuild] WebApplication2.sln: Build default targets
[22:31:54][WebApplication2.sln] ValidateSolutionConfiguration
[22:31:54][ValidateSolutionConfiguration] Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
[22:31:54][WebApplication2.sln] Build
[22:31:54][Build] MSBuild
[22:31:54][MSBuild] WebApplication2\WebApplication2.csproj: Build default targets
[22:31:54][WebApplication2\WebApplication2.csproj] EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports
[22:31:54][EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports] Error
[22:31:54][Error] R:\teamcity\buildAgent\work\5cfc9181ba33f9ec\WebApplication2\WebApplication2.csproj(282, 5): This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props.
[22:31:54][Step 1/1] MSBuild command line parameters contain "/property:" or "/p:". It is recommended to define System Property on Build Parameters instead.
[22:31:54][Step 1/1] Process exited with code 1
[22:31:54][Step 1/1] MSBuild output
[22:31:54][MSBuild output] Start MSBuild...
[22:31:54][MSBuild output] 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe' '"@R:\teamcity\buildAgent\work\5cfc9181ba33f9ec\WebApplication2.sln.teamcity.msbuild.tcargs" R:\teamcity\buildAgent\work\5cfc9181ba33f9ec\WebApplication2.sln.teamcity'
[22:31:54][MSBuild output] working dir = 'R:\teamcity\buildAgent\work\5cfc9181ba33f9ec'
[22:31:54][MSBuild output] Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.7.2046.0
[22:31:54][MSBuild output] [Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.42000]
[22:31:54][MSBuild output] Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
[22:31:54][MSBuild output] 
[22:31:54][MSBuild output] Build started 14/08/2017 10:31:54 PM.
[22:31:54][MSBuild output] Project "R:\teamcity\buildAgent\work\5cfc9181ba33f9ec\WebApplication2.sln.teamcity" on node 1 (TeamCity_Generated_Build target(s)).
[22:31:54][MSBuild output] Project "R:\teamcity\buildAgent\work\5cfc9181ba33f9ec\WebApplication2.sln.teamcity" (1) is building "R:\teamcity\buildAgent\work\5cfc9181ba33f9ec\WebApplication2.sln" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
[22:31:54][MSBuild output] ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
[22:31:54][MSBuild output]   Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
[22:31:54][MSBuild output] Project "R:\teamcity\buildAgent\work\5cfc9181ba33f9ec\WebApplication2.sln" (2) is building "R:\teamcity\buildAgent\work\5cfc9181ba33f9ec\WebApplication2\WebApplication2.csproj" (3) on node 1 (default targets).
[22:31:54][MSBuild output] R:\teamcity\buildAgent\work\5cfc9181ba33f9ec\WebApplication2\WebApplication2.csproj(282,5): error : This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props.
[22:31:54][MSBuild output] Done Building Project "R:\teamcity\buildAgent\work\5cfc9181ba33f9ec\WebApplication2\WebApplication2.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
[22:31:54][MSBuild output] Done Building Project "R:\teamcity\buildAgent\work\5cfc9181ba33f9ec\WebApplication2.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.
[22:31:54][MSBuild output] Done Building Project "R:\teamcity\buildAgent\work\5cfc9181ba33f9ec\WebApplication2.sln.teamcity" (TeamCity_Generated_Build target(s)) -- FAILED.
[22:31:54][MSBuild output] 
[22:31:54][MSBuild output] Build FAILED.
[22:31:54][MSBuild output] 
[22:31:54][MSBuild output] "R:\teamcity\buildAgent\work\5cfc9181ba33f9ec\WebApplication2.sln.teamcity" (TeamCity_Generated_Build target) (1) ->
[22:31:54][MSBuild output] "R:\teamcity\buildAgent\work\5cfc9181ba33f9ec\WebApplication2.sln" (default target) (2) ->
[22:31:54][MSBuild output] "R:\teamcity\buildAgent\work\5cfc9181ba33f9ec\WebApplication2\WebApplication2.csproj" (default target) (3) ->
[22:31:54][MSBuild output] (EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports target) -> 
[22:31:54][MSBuild output]   R:\teamcity\buildAgent\work\5cfc9181ba33f9ec\WebApplication2\WebApplication2.csproj(282,5): error : This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props.
[22:31:54][MSBuild output] 
[22:31:54][MSBuild output]     0 Warning(s)
[22:31:54][MSBuild output]     1 Error(s)
[22:31:54][MSBuild output] 
[22:31:54][MSBuild output] Time Elapsed 00:00:00.19
[22:31:55][Step 1/1] Process exited with code 1
[22:31:54][Step 1/1] Step Build and Deploy (MSBuild) failed
```

This is what I use in Command line parameter in the step:

```
/p:Configuration=Debug
/p:DeployOnBuild=true 
/p:WebPublishMethod=Package 
/p:PackageAsSingleFile=true 
/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true
/p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0 
/p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"
```

Let me know if I missed something or not properly coded in the Command line parameter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First install NuGet.exe in TeamCity Tools.
[image]

Then just added another build step before your code compile to restore nuget packages in the project.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the project or solution file.

```
  msbuild .\WebApplication2.sln /p:Configuration=Debug
 /p:OutputPath=bin
 /p:DeployOnBuild=True 
 /p:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish
```

Or you have to have spaces in your project file names, than you must add quotes around.

Comment: I am still getting the same result for it.