# Why i cannot build the test project in Msbuild Teamcity using the project solution file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, msbuild, teamcity

```
UnitTest1.cs(131,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestMethodAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

16:42:40
        UnitTest1.cs(131,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestMethod' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

16:42:40
        UnitTest1.cs(144,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestMethodAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Did you use the path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` to build your project? If not, please try this.

Comment: i am running in the build server

Comment: Did you build your project successfully locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why i cannot build the test project in Msbuild Teamcity using the
>   project solution file?

First of all, you should make sure that you can build your test project successfully locally.

Then, follow these suggestions:

**Suggestions**

**First**, Before `Teamcity 9.1.5`, you should install `Microsoft Visual Studio edition` on the build agent and make sure that you install the right version. Please see [this official document](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/MSTest+Support).

**Since** `TeamCity 9.1.5`, the Visual Studio Test Runner supports Visual Studio Test Agent installed on the agent machine (Microsoft Visual Studio is no longer required). You can refer to [this link](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Visual+Studio+Tests).

**Second**, you should do the restoration of the nuget packages at VCS before build step.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45675799/restore-nuget-package-in-teamcity-build-and-deploy-step).